# Using trim function with special characters

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column (A) of values that I would like to trim to the left. Each value in column A has a / in it which separates a word in German and it's English translation. For example one value would be "nein / no". (note there is a space between the two words.

What I want to do is write a trim function that starts after the space that follows the /. In othe words I want the value in my example to trim from "nein / no" to just "no". The part that confuses me is the fact that each value changes in size so I don't know how to tell excel where to trim from. My code should look something like this

```
For each cl in range("A1:A300"). Trim cl.value. Next cl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Dim start As Long

    For Each cl In Range("A1:A300")
        str = c1

        start = InStr(1, str, "/", vbTextCompare) + 1

        strVal = Trim(Right(str, Len(str) - start))
        msgbox strVal 
    Next cl
```

Comment: +1 for going the extra mile, using `InStr` and `start` variable :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with something like this:

```
For each cl in Range("A1:A300")
    With cl
        .Value = Trim(Len(.Value) - Right(.Value, _
             Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("/", .Value)))
    End With
Next
```

Comment: +1 For reaching 4000 and contributing so well to this forum. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA to solve this. A simple formula will suffice:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1))
```

---

nein / no = **no**

---

lederhosen / breeches = **breeches**

---

doppelganger / doppelganger = **doppelganger**

Comment: +1 for a good solution, however, if OP is asking for a VBA solution, probably safe to assume that this is being performed as *part* of a larger subroutine, in which case VBA is probably necessary :)

Comment: @DavidZemens, you're probably right, but I wouldn't assume it. Many questions are asked by people who simply don't know how to approach what they want to do. I'm just happy I got to use "doppelganger" in an answer!